# molecule lint - Error: No such command 'lint'

Tags: ansible, molecule, ansible-lint

I am trying to understand how to configure Ansible linting as part of my testing phase but unfortunately all information and documentation out there about molecule seems to be outdated.

First, this is the molecule version I am running:

```bash
molecule --version  molecule 6.0.2 using python 3.12      
ansible:2.16.0     
azure:23.5.0 from molecule_plugins     
containers:23.5.0 from molecule_plugins requiring collections: ansible.posix>=1.3.0 community.docker>=1.9.1 containers.podman>=1.8.1     
default:6.0.2 from molecule     
docker:23.5.0 from molecule_plugins requiring collections: community.docker>=3.0.2 ansible.posix>=1.4.0     
ec2:23.5.0 from molecule_plugins     
gce:23.5.0 from molecule_plugins requiring collections: google.cloud>=1.0.2 community.crypto>=1.8.0     
podman:23.5.0 from molecule_plugins requiring collections: containers.podman>=1.7.0 ansible.posix>=1.3.0     vagrant:23.5.0 from molecule_plugins
```

And this is my `molecule.yml` file.

```yaml
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
  options:
    requirements-file: requirements.yml
platforms:
  - name: molecule-debian
    image: debian:12
driver:
  options:
    managed: False
    login_cmd_template: "podman exec -ti {instance} bash"
    ansible_connection_options:
      ansible_connection: podman
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  lint:
    name: ansible-lint
    enabled: True
lint: ansible-lint
verifier:
  name: ansible
```

When running `molecule test` all steps are running as expected, however I don't see any errors coming from the linter.

Also, it seems the `molecule lint` command has been removed. There is a `syntax` step in the default scenario, but I was unable to figure our how to use it. Again, docs are not helping.

**What's the proper way to manage the linting phase as part of the Ansible code testing with Molecule?**

```bash
% molecule matrix test
INFO     Test matrix
---                                                                                                                                                                   
default:                                                                                                                                                              
  - dependency                                                                                                                                                        
  - cleanup                                                                                                                                                           
  - destroy                                                                                                                                                           
  - syntax                                                                                                                                                            
  - create                                                                                                                                                            
  - prepare                                                                                                                                                           
  - converge                                                                                                                                                          
  - idempotence                                                                                                                                                       
  - side_effect                                                                                                                                                       
  - verify                                                                                                                                                            
  - cleanup                                                                                                                                                           
  - destroy 

% molecule lint
Usage: molecule [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'molecule --help' for help.

Error: No such command 'lint'.
```

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, this is of course on purpose. New way is to run the linters separately.

https://github.com/ansible/molecule/discussions/3914